# SqlAlchemy + MySql 1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to delete a row from two tables User and UserRoleMapping.

> UserRoleMapping is referenced to User table using User.id => UserRoleMapping.user_id.

I need to delete a row from both the tables using the user specific id.

My code

```
session_delete_mapping = Session()
session_delete_user= Session()
if request.method == "POST":
    user_id = request.form['user_list']
    try :
        num_rows_deleted_map = session_delete_mapping.query(UserRoleMapping).filter(UserRoleMapping.user_id == user_id).delete()
        num_rows_deleted_user = session_delete_user.query(UserRoleMapping).filter(User.id == user_id).delete()
        session_delete_mapping.commit()
        session_delete_user.commit()
        User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).delete()
        flash("Successfully deleted !!")
    except Exception as e:
        flash("Oops something went wrong : "+ str(e))
        session_delete_mapping.rollback()
        session_delete_user.rollback()
return render_template('index.html')
```

but my code throws an exception

> (InternalError) (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction') 'DELETE FROM user_role_mapping WHERE user_role_mapping.user_id = %s' ('3',)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use retry package.

```
pip install retry
from sqlalchemy import exc

@retry(exc.OperationError, delay=5, tries=5)
def fun_name():
    try:
        #body of function
    except exc.OperationError:
        raise
```

It will retry for 5 times with delaying 5 seconds when an operation error occurs

Answer (score -1):

This happens when server cannot acquire lock to process actions with table or database, try restarting transaction as advised in the exception:

```
session_delete_mapping = Session()
session_delete_user= Session()
if request.method == "POST":
    user_id = request.form['user_list']
    try :
        num_rows_deleted_map = session_delete_mapping.query(UserRoleMapping).filter(UserRoleMapping.user_id == user_id).delete()
        num_rows_deleted_user = session_delete_user.query(UserRoleMapping).filter(User.id == user_id).delete()
        session_delete_mapping.commit()
        session_delete_user.commit()
        User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).delete()
        flash("Successfully deleted !!")
    except InternalError as e:
        # mysql error code of 'lock timeout'
        if e.orig[0] == 1205:
            # call this handler again with same arguments
        else:
            flash("Oops something went wrong : "+ str(e))
            session_delete_mapping.rollback()
            session_delete_user.rollback()
    except Exception as e:
        flash("Oops something went wrong : "+ str(e))
        session_delete_mapping.rollback()
        session_delete_user.rollback()
return render_template('index.html')
```

Don't forget to import exception class you catching `from sqlalchemy.exc import InternalError`

Normally you can get this exception very rarely, but if not you should check your server for huge or "stalled" queries and optimise them. 
And of coarse you can increase `wait_timeout` in myslq config file.